# a second ng-tables in my angularjs controler

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ngtable

is it possible to load two ng-tables in one controller. My ng-repeat used the variable $data.
How can I work with ng-table with another table?

Rg, Chris

Here my example.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tRMlPdBF2MKrpty9JLk5?p=preview

Comment: Please post your code and what you have tried.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/tRMlPdBF2MKrpty9JLk5?p=preview

Comment: the plunker is broken

Comment: "My ng-repeat used the variable $data. How can I work with ng-table with another table?" <- what does this mean?

Comment: can I have two ng-tables in one controller?

Comment: yes, there is no limitation on things within a controller